# Set a select input of a html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to select a specific `select` input from a form, where I use `select2` library. The [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options) writes:

> To programmatically select an option/item for a Select2 control, use
>   the jQuery .val() method:

```
$('#mySelect2').val('1'); // Select the option with a value of '1'
```

So, I try to set the input with the value `0`. However, the input isn't changed.. . What I am missing?

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  allowClear: true
});

var myFlag = 0;

$("#haslabel").val(myFlag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" id="hasLabel" name="hasLabel">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">yes</option>
              <option value="0">no</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Spell the selector correctly
2. 0 and 1 are false and true - use the strings
3. val("0") sets the value but does not show it unless you trigger change to see it
4. Alternatively have the option selected `<option value="0" selected>no</option>`

***Note***: to not see `...`,  your select has to be wide enough

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hasLabel').select2({allowClear: true});
  $('#hasLabel').val("0").trigger("change"); // set AND show
});
```

```css
.js-states { width:70px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" id="hasLabel" name="hasLabel">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">yes</option>
              <option value="0">no</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, I just noticed one more error of my implementation..
I wasn't selecting the `hasLabel` but the `haslabel`...

Comment: That does not help either :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading the document which you provides and what I noticed was this:

> Select2 will listen for the change event on the  element that
>   it is attached to. When you make any external changes that need to be
>   reflected in Select2 (such as changing the value), you should trigger
>   this event.

This means that when you set a value programmatically, you need to trigger the 'change' manually, so like

```
$("#haslabel").val(myFlag).trigger("change");
```

Comment: I beat you to it. Took me far too long to find that